# How Static members will accees when constructor is invoked

Tags: class, constructor, static, static-members

I have some part of which is working without any errors and giving the results

But I want to know how it is working

```
static int count = 0;
{
    count++;
}

Constructor() {
}

CoOnstructor(int i) {
    System.out.println("Int argument");
}

CoOnstructor(double d) {
    System.out.println("double argument");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Constructor t1 = new CoOnstructor();
    Constructor t2 = new Constructor(10);
    Constructor t3 = new Constructor(10.5);

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

In the output is showing count value as 3. By looking at the result I understand that when the constructor is invoked the value of count is incremented. Which is static member. Is this because of declaration of static member if in way of function like the below

```
static int count = 0;
{
    count++;
}
```

I know that when the constructor is invoked all the class members will accessed

Does anyone have links explanation for this type of code?

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using (eg "java")

Comment: take an example for C# only. But i think it is related to OOPS concepts only